# How do I generate urls for dynamically generated images?

Tags: django, django-templates

Only started messing around with Django yesterday and I've been stuck on this issue now for 5+ hours. I have a page which is a table, and the plan is for it to look like:

```
Name  -  Total Badges -  Badges
Bob   -             1 -  @(level 3)
Mike  -             3 -  @(level 5) | &(level 7)  | $(level 19)
```

In reality there will likely be hundreds of unique images representing several dozen "badges" (not actually using badges... Just image representations of items with a counter overlayed on it). In the table template, I have tried half a million different ways of trying to generate a url that links to an internal image. One example that I've tried which should illustrate what my intentions are is:

```
...
<tr> Name </tr>
<tr> Total Badges </tr>
<tr> Badges </tr>

{% if profile %}
{% for name, badges in profile %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{ name }} </td>
    <td> {{ badges.count_all }} </td>
    {% for badge in badges %}
    {% static "MyApp/Images/{{badge}}.png" as image %}
    <img src="{{ image }}">
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

What happens with that is it generates the circle and triangle error image. But if I hard coded {% static "MyApp/Images/AmpersandBadge100.png" %} it works. I think that instead of replacing the {{ badge }} var it is simply rendering it as "MyApp/Images/{{ badge }}.png".

I don't even know what to google for and 4 hours of scouring over the documentation has led me to believe that static file are the only way to display internal images. But that probably isn't true.

Comment: Normally you can just use `{{ image.url }}`, but what does your models.py look like?

Answer (score 0):

I googled some more after posting and after some tinkering finally found a solution that worked.

```
{% for name, badges in profile %}

...

  <td>
  {% for badge in badges %}
     ## {{ badge }}s look like "MyApp/images/%s.png"%badge
    <img src="{% static "" %}{{ badge}}">
```

Not sure how it works but it does.